# Excel Lookup 2 condition

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a data table:

[image]

I want this result:

[image]

Like first match account, second match option only have 3 option always I like to array number.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you checked the many Q&A on here asking the same thing?

Comment: I Did Not Found Please If Any Have Like This Send me

Comment: Edit this to suit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71894910/4961700

Comment: Hi @SolarMike I Need Array Results Like Banana 1,12,1

Comment: So, when I said "edit to suit" what have you now tried? In that 3 minutes?

Comment: @SolarMike yes its give me only one resutls

Comment: @SolarMike I want Match Account, Option To Give me number in array

Comment: Where is 324 account in your desired result? I think, it would be a good idea to edit your question and explain **in words** what you try accomplishing and based on which logic/algorithm.

Comment: What "To Give me number in array" does mean? Which array are you talking about? What does "Pkt,," represents in the "Apple" column for the desired result?  Should it be "Pkt,2,4", but you were too lazy to show it as it should? 2345 accound does not have any numeric value in "NUMBER" column. Where from did "Pkt.1,12.1" does come?

Comment: @FaneDuru he pkt is simple string and value come to number column who macth same account and option

Comment: Your comment does not clarify anything. **I asked you strait questions**. **Are you able to answer them**? Or should we solve a kind of puzzle to qualify ourself for solving  your 'special' problem?

Comment: If you decide not to further explain your desired result, and do not share what you've tried. You should at least check the desired results are correct. I doubt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It should return as looks to be logical according to your question and comments. It assumes that your picture representing desired output is wrong. It returns in the same sheet starting from "E1". Of course, it may be easily adapted to return anywhere:

```
Sub TestExtractFruitsPerAccount()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrIt, i As Long 
   Dim arrFin, j As Long, dict As Object

   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
   arr = sh.Range("A1:C" & lastR).value
   
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
            dict.Add arr(i, 1), Array(arr(i, 2) & "|" & arr(i, 3))
        Else
            arrIt = dict(arr(i, 1)): ReDim Preserve arrIt(UBound(arrIt) + 1)
            arrIt(UBound(arrIt)) = arr(i, 2) & "|" & arr(i, 3)
            dict(arr(i, 1)) = arrIt
        End If
   Next i

   ReDim arrFin(1 To dict.count, 1 To 4)
   Dim strApp As String, strBan As String, strMng As String
   
   For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
        arrFin(i + 1, 1) = dict.Keys()(i)
        arrIt = dict.Items()(i)
        For j = 0 To UBound(arrIt)
            Select Case Split(arrIt(j), "|")(1)
                Case "APPLE"
                    If strApp = "" Then
                        strApp = "Pkt." & Split(arrIt(j), "|")(0)
                    Else
                        strApp = strApp & "," & Split(arrIt(j), "|")(0)
                    End If
                Case "BANANA"
                    If strBan = "" Then
                        strBan = "Pkt." & Split(arrIt(j), "|")(0)
                    Else
                        strBan = strBan & "," & Split(arrIt(j), "|")(0)
                    End If
                Case "MANGO"
                    If strMng = "" Then
                        strMng = "Pkt." & Split(arrIt(j), "|")(0)
                    Else
                        strMng = strMng & "," & Split(arrIt(j), "|")(0)
                    End If
            End Select
        Next j

        If strApp <> "" Then arrFin(i + 1, 2) = strApp
        If strBan <> "" Then arrFin(i + 1, 3) = strBan
        If strMng <> "" Then arrFin(i + 1, 4) = strMng
        strApp = "": strBan = "": strMng = ""
   Next i
   sh.Range("E1").Resize(1, 4).value = Array("Account", "APPLE", "BANANA", "MANGO")
   sh.Range("E2").Resize(dict.count, 4).value = arrFin
End Sub
```

I took your question as a challenge, even if it is at least strange according to my taste.

Please, test it and send some feedback. Isn't it what you need? If not, please try better describing what you need against what the above code returns.

If something unclear, please do not hesitate to ask for clarifications. I can comment the code lines. I posted it as it is, in order to be sure that you will see it. Your question, as it is, most probably will be deleted...